# Displaying TensorflowExtended/TFX results of visualize_statistics

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfx

I'm trying to display the output of visualize_statistics like below but the results are pretty disappointing:

```
train_stats = tfdv.generate_statistics_from_tfrecord(data_location='data/tf_records/train.record')
test_stats = tfdv.generate_statistics_from_tfrecord(data_location='data/tf_records/test.record')

schema = tfdv.infer_schema(train_stats)

tfdv.visualize_statistics(lhs_statistics=test_stats, rhs_statistics=train_stats, lhs_name='TEST_DATASET', rhs_name='TRAIN_DATASET')
```

Result:

```
<IPython.core.display.HTML object>
```

How can I improve on this?

I do not want to install Apache Beam

I do not want to install Apache Airflow

I do not want to install Kubeflow

I do not want to display a notebook

I only want to display the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you could write those statistics to a text file using [`write_stats_text`](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/data_validation/api_docs/python/tfdv/write_stats_text)?